# Convert RealmResults<E> to List<E> with copyFromRealm

Tags: android, realm

How can I convert `RealmResults<E>` to `List<E>`?

I tried with method `copyFromRealm`:

```
RealmResults<EventRealm> result = realm.where(EventRealm.class).findAll();

EventRealm eventRealm = result.get(0);
int id = eventRealm.getId(); // return id 2564
String title = eventRealm.getTitle(); // return "My event"

List<EventRealm> copied = realm.copyFromRealm(result);

EventRealm eventRealm1 = copied.get(0);
int id1 = eventRealm1.getId(); // return id 0
String title1 = eventRealm1.getTitle(); // return "My event"
```

But not quite understand why in copy `getTitle()` give correct result, but `getId()` incorrect.

Model

```
public class EventRealm extends RealmObject {

        @PrimaryKey
        private int id;
        private String title;

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = this.id;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is your `setId` method.

Right now it does this:

```
public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = this.id;
}
```

It should be

```
public void setId(int id) {
  this.id = id;
}
```

Comment: I am ashamed, I am sorry that your time spent